# Use of unresolved identifier vDSP_vsq in Xcode 6.1, Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, accelerate-framework

I'm using Accelerate.framework to get some informations,

It works fine on iOS Device, but occurred error when I using Simulator,

Use of unresolved identifier vDSP_vsq

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like an issue of swift accelerate.framework

it works when I using the method on Objective-C class, then call it by bridging-header